# How To parse JSON data without JSON array?

Tags: android, json, web-services

Below is JSON Link

```
{
"AF": {
    "country_name": "Afghanistan",
    "dialling_code": "+93"
},
"AL": {
    "country_name": "Albania",
    "dialling_code": "+355"
},
"DZ": {
    "country_name": "Algeria",
    "dialling_code": "+213"
},
```

From the above JSON link I'm trying to retrieve data from the JSON by using the below code.

```
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            countryname = jsonObject.getString("country_name");
            dialingcode = jsonObject.getString("dialling_code");
            Log.d("COUNTRYNAME", countryname);
            Log.d("DIALER_CODE", dialingcode);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `Keys` from `JSONObject` and iterate on keys . below is an example.

```
private void parse(String jsonString) {
    try {
        JSONObject resObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        Iterator<String> iterator = resObject.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();// key can be used as Country code
            JSONObject data = resObject.getJSONObject(key);
            String country_name = data.getString("country_name");
            String dialling_code = data.getString("dialling_code");

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can fetch all keys into a List or ArrayList and then loop this ArrayList to fetch the details of each JSON key.

```
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
    Iterator keys= jsonObject .keys();
   while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        JSONObject data = resObject.getJSONObject(key);
        String country_name = data.getString("country_name");
        String dialling_code = data.getString("dialling_code");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your json response");

        Iterator  iteratorObj = jsonObject.keys();

        while (iteratorObj.hasNext())
        {
            String JsonObjCountryCode = (String)iteratorObj.next();

            Log.i("Country Code key", JsonObjCountryCode);

            JSONObject jo_code = jsonObject.getJSONObject(JsonObjCountryCode);

            Iterator<String> keys = jo_code.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext())
            {
                String key = keys.next();
                String value = jo_code.getString(key);
                Log.i("country_name value", value);

            }

        }

} 
catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```